# "Implementation" of the object hierarchy - "the easiest way" or how to avoiding virtual inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I have some quite complex, virtual objects hierarchy that represents all the elements in 3D Engine as abstract classes (interfaces).

For example, I have `Renderable` which parent is `Sizeable` (with `getSize()` method). `Sizeable` inherits from `Positionable` (with `getPosition()`) etc.

That structure is fine and logic (e.g. 3D Model is `Renderable`, bone of skeleton for skinning is `Sizeable`, and the Camera is only `Positionable`).

There is also one **"uber-class"**, `Engine3D`.

**My aim is:**

I have to write the "implementation" for that "graphic things" (module). It will be DirectX "implementation". **The aim:** the programmer that uses my "implementation" can switch to other fast and simple (which implementation he uses is almost transparent to him).

I would like to keep it that way:

```
//choosing module "implementation" ("implementation" mentioned here only)
Engine3D * engine = new MyEngine3D();

Renderable * model = engine->createModel(...);
//line above will return MyRenderable class in fact,
//but user (programmer) will treat it as Renderable
```

Why I want to create "own" versions of `Renderable` and all others? Because they will share some "implementation"-specific data (pointers for DirectX structures etc.).

**My problem is:**

But that way, I would create a "mirror" - a copy of the original module's objects hierarchy with `My` in front of each class name. Moreover, `MyRenderable` would have to inherit both from `Renderable` (to overwide `render()`) and `MySizeable` (to get the DirectX matrices etc.).

**And that involves the virtual inheritance and really complicates the structure.**

### Is there an easier way?

I'm speaking mainly about avoiding virtual multi-inheritance (just multi-inheritance is fine, I guess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely avoid a strong coupling of object hierarchy and rendering implementation. My suggestion would be to move all the DirectX specific code to a class outside of your object hierarchy, for example an `IRenderer` interface together with a `DirectXRenderer` implementation. Add a reference or pointer to `IRenderer` to all the classes which have to draw something (`Renderable`, etc). All object classes must use your own implementations of matrices etc. to keep them independent from the data structures of the actual rendering backend.

Comment: I do it (partly) by the way I described. I move the DirectX specific code to the hierarchy of objects that is corresponding to my abstract tree of data. But you know, Renderable has common render() method, Materialable has common methods with shaders etc. - it's not just one uniform IRenderer that can handle all the types (lines, bones, meshes...) - I use DirectX not only to use render() but also for skin calculations, shaders settings, texture pointers etc. - some of object in that hierachy has them, some of them not. But still, I see some point in changing IS-A to HAS-A.

Comment: You don't have to use a single IRenderer implementation. There can be another - less complex - hierarchy below the Renderer as well if you need that, although you should not duplicate the object hierarchy in your rendering hierarchy. The point is that you need a (thin) interface between the renderer and the objects which abstracts the dependencies if you'd ever intended to use another renderer like OpenGL or something (separation of concerns).

Comment: Ok, but you know - "the interface between the renderer and the objects of game" (player, NPC etc.) that separates them from OGL/DirectX supposed to be the objects of my hierarchy (that was the purpose of creating them). And the complexity of that hierarchy is all about handling DirectX/OGL operations (shaders, textures, ray calculations, matrices...). So it is: Player (uses his component)->Renderable (my hierarchy)->RenerableDX (my implementation) or Player->Renderable->RenderableOGL

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. I thought the purpose of creating this object hierarchy was also to enable the user to build a scene by adding class instances to a tree.

Comment: User should not add any new class to the tree - it exists to separate DX/OGL from him and will be delivered as abstract library + two implementations (DX/OGL) from which he can choose one. Then he can use the objects of the tree (create, manipulate) so he can do something in 3D scene without even knowing if DX or OGL will do the calculations/render for him. So yes, he adds instances of objects, but he does NOT add new types to the tree. Sorry if I did not make it clear at the beginning.

Comment: Ok so I understood correctly. I wrote 'adding class __instances__ to a tree' to form a scene. Of course the user does not need to create new classes. Take a look at some already existing 3D engine implementations. Most of them use the approach I mentioned. One example is the OGRE engine which uses a separate class `RenderSystem` with implementations `GLRenderSystem` etc. None of the scene building classes use any code specific to OpenGL or DirectX.